# A filter in a subset of a topological vector space by a sequence

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, filters

Let $E$ be a topological vector space, $A \subseteq E$ and $S:=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots\}$ a sequence in $A$. I know that, if for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we define
$$S_n:=\{x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\cdots\}$$
then the family $B:=\{S_n \subset A \; ; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a base for the filter $\mathcal{F}_S$  given by
$$\mathcal{F}_S=\{B\subset E \; ; \; S_n \subset B, \:\text{for some} \: n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

A priori, the filter $\mathcal{F}_S$ is a filter in $E$. It's this filter a filter in $A$ too?

Moreover, if $S$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, then $\mathcal{F}_S$ a Cauchy filter in $A$?

Comment: Your $\mathcal F_S$ son't be a filter on $A$ (unless $A=E$), because it contains $E$. But a slight modification, $\{B\subseteq A:S_n\subseteq B\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a filter on $A$. It will be a Cauchy filter if and only if $\mathcal F_S$ is a Cauchy filter (if and only if $S$ is a Cauchy sequence).

Comment: But$ \{B\subseteq A \; ; \; S_n \subseteq B, \:\text{for some} \: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is the filter generated by $B$?

Comment: It's the filter on $A$ generated by the tails of $S$.  ($B$ is just a bound variable; replacing it with other symbols like $Z$ or $\theta$ would make no difference.)

Comment: Understand. You could even put your first comment as an answer.